# ENTITY_IS_DELETED error when loading Detail records with External Id

Tags: master-detail, externalid, isdeleted

I have a Master-Detail relationship between 2 objects. The child object has a unique External Id field that I'm using to handle duplicates during database commits. The scenario that falls apart is as follows:

1. Create a Master with a Detail record whose External Id = "MyUniqueId"
2. Delete the Master record
3. Insert a new Master record
4. Insert a new Detail record with External Id = "MyUniqueId"
5. Error: ENTITY_IS_DELETED, entity is deleted

I am doing steps 3 onward in Apex but I'm pretty sure the same error happens when loading records through the API (e.g. DataLoader).

Does this mean the Master-Detail model is working to my disadvantage here and therefore should either not be used or complemented with a trigger that explicitly deletes the children when the Master is deleted? Both choices are quite sub-optimal, so I'd appreciate any and all other alternatives.

Comment: What happens if you clear them from the `Recycle Bin`? You might be able to avoid the issue by simply hard-deleting the detail records.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't want to delete them from the bin. Also hard-deleting defeats the purpose of having a Master-Detail relationship in some ways and therefore is not an optimal choice for me. I am hoping I can have the cake and eat it too!

Comment: So out of curiosity, why are you inserting two seemingly distinct records with the same unique identifier?

Comment: 1) Some records might have been deleted in production by mistake. So we want to have a way to reload everything to their original state. 2) Some records may have been legitimately deleted. Later on we want to load a new record with the same external Id but different information. One could ask, if you have such a use-case why are you using a unique Id that has the potential for reuse? The answer is, the benefits of using an external Id outweigh the cons. Basically I am trying to address a scenario that has a 1% chance of happening.

Comment: You could perhaps write a `REST` service that looks up that unique identifier in the `Recycle Bin`. If it's there, `undelete` the existing record. Otherwise, `insert`  a new one.

Comment: @AdrianLarson But the record may not be in the Recycle Bin anymore. Btw just as a general pointer, even by emptying the Bin the error doesn't go away. At least that's the behaviour in my unit tests.

Comment: @Mossi Ever figure out a solution to this? I'm getting exact same thing, though only happens when use `allOrNothing` = false.